# Android TabHost Layout Question

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-linearlayout, android-framelayout

This is my first tabbed application for Android. I walked through the "HelloTabWidget" app on androids website, but I can't figure out how to add content to the tabs. The FrameLayout stacks stuff on top of each other to the top left (from what I've read). I added a couple of textviews and an imageView, but it only displays the last item added. Is there a way to use Linear Layout instead of Frame Layout? If not, how can you place multiple views in the tab? The only thing I have done different from the example is I added a 4th tab. In one of the tab Activities I inserted the following code to try to get multiple items to display:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    

        TextView textview = new TextView(this);
        textview.setText("This is the About tab");
        setContentView(textview);

        TextView textview2 = new TextView(this);
        textview2.setText("About Test");
        setContentView(textview2);

        ImageView imgView = new ImageView(this);
        imgView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.header));
        setContentView(imgView);
    }
```

Here is the link to the example I followed:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is your layout xml file? I use this and I can stack several textview in every tab. TabActivity:

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</TabHost>
```

Activity inside tab:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textOne" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textTwo" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<LinearLayout>
```

I'm a newbie myself, so there might be a better way to do it. This works for me, though.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I don't have multiple layout files. In the example, it just had the main.xml and you populate each tab in Java. How would I go about adding another layout file for each tab, while keeping the tabs in view?

Comment: In about the same way. Use the first layout for the tabs, and in each tab set a different activity. In those activities you create the layout by code, as you did in the snippet you give. The only note (I might be wrong), you should use setContenteView() only once. Create a LinearLayout or whatever and put the TextViews in it. Then set it as the content view.

Comment: I don't guess I'm understanding how you are doing it. If you use setContentView() and send in a new layout, it will go on top of the layout that has the tabs, right? If you have this running, could you show me some more code? Maybe one of the activities code? Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry I misread your comment.To add activities to the Tabs refer to Cristian's code.To create a layout file you create a new activity1.xml in your res/layout folder.From your inner activity you do onCreate(){super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);setContentView(R.layout.activity1);}and inside there you put whatever logic your activity follows.Of course,you will have a different activity for each tab.The layout files, that depends if you reuse the same layout in every tab or not.How to create new layouts and activities are very basic concepts,though.Maybe you should go back to the doc as well.

Comment: I apologize for my misunderstanding. I thought that if I used a setContentView(R.layout.newxmllayout) it would over ride the layout the tabs were in, and hide the tabs. I just got back to my computer and tried it anyways and it worked ok. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't read the example carefully. Take a look at the point number 6; you will see something like:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ArtistsActivity.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Artists",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AlbumsActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("albums").setIndicator("Albums",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_albums))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SongsActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("songs").setIndicator("Songs",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_songs))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
}
```

That's what you put in the onCreate for the `TabActivity`. As you can see it has 3 activities. What you are doing is using JUST ONE activity and setting the content view 3 times, which is obviously wrong.

So... how to make it work? First, read again the tutorial. Second, create one activity for each tab you want to show. And use the model above to add those activities to your `TabHost`.

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. That is what I have in the main class. The code I posted was in the, for example, ArtistsActivity class. In the example, they only use a single textView, where I added another textView and an ImageView.

Comment: In that case, concentrate on that activity and read the LinearLayout tutorial http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html You are almost there!

Comment: I know how to use LinearLayout (at least using it in the xml). However, since I am using a tab host and there is only 1 main xml file, I have to add the contents to each tab in Java (like the code in my original post). With the code I posted, I am trying to add 3 items to a single tab, the problem is only the last thing I add can be seen. In my main XML file, I have <TabHost> <LinearLayout> <TabWidget/> <FrameLayout> <LinearLayout/>. I don't know how else to explain it.

Comment: Basically, if I want to add 2 textViews on top of each other in one tab, how do I do this (assuming I followed the HelloTabWidget example)? You can't just simply add it to the XML file because that would add the textView to all tabs, right?